# Problem with the copy constructor of an class holden in boost::variant

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant

I've tried to construct a tree structure using boost::variant and now I have some problems.
I implemented a copy constructor in the class holden in boost::variant and call the copy constructor
just like this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>


struct Hoge{
int i;
Hoge(int j) : i(j){};
Hoge(Hoge const& hoge) : i(hoge.i) {}
};

using var = boost::variant<int,Hoge>;

int main()
{
var hoge = Hoge(1);
var hogehoge = Hoge(hoge);
}
```

A compile failed because of no matching function for call to ‘Hoge::Hoge(var&)’.

How to fix this code? Should the copy constructor has an argument boost::variant?
Or can I fix this code with an brilliant boost technique?

Comment: How do you expect the compiler to pick one constructor over the other?
Use `boost::get` to specify the type you want explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not copy constructing: that would be like saying:

```
var hogehoge = var(hoge); // elided assign of copy-ctor
```

Or indeed just

```
var hogehoge(hoge);
var hogehoge = hoge;
```

So, what you need is to SAY you want a `Hoge` to copy,

```
var hogehoge = boost::get<Hoge>(hoge); // may throw if `hoge` holds int
```

So you copy-construct Hoge, which you then *convert-construct* to the variant type.

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/517172173965a762)**

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct Hoge {
    int i;
    Hoge(int j) : i(j){};
    Hoge(Hoge const& hoge) : i(hoge.i) {}
};

using var = boost::variant<int, Hoge>;

int main() {
    var hoge = Hoge(1);
    var hogehoge = boost::get<Hoge>(hoge);
}
```